# Is it possible to add SQL comments to a query built with the ORM?

Tags: sql, django, orm, comments

I am trying to identify slow queries in a large-scale Django 1.3 web application. As it is kind of difficult to match the raw sql query in the slow query log with the specific ORM statement in the code, I wondered if it is possible to add a SQL comment to the query constructed with the ORM, something like..

```
Object.objects.filter(Q(pub_date__lte=datetime.now)).comment('query no. 123')
```

Comment: Related, but an a real answer: http://code.playfire.com/django-append-url-to-sql/

Comment: That doesn't help at all to solve the described problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: That was supposed to say "but not a real answer"... can't seem to edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those reading in 2022 onwards - there is a much better answer these days:

[Google's sqlcommenter project has a Django middleware](https://google.github.io/sqlcommenter/python/django/)

> [A] Django middleware whose purpose is to augment a SQL statement right before execution, with information about the controller and user code to help with later making database optimization decisions, after those statements are examined from the database server’s logs.

Answer (score 8):

Solution found by using **.extra()** for raw SQL commands on the django-user mailinglist:

```
Object.objects.filter(Q(pub_date__lte=datetime.now()).extra(where=['1=1 /* query no. 123 */'])
```